# Jscrollpane - Fires a function when isAtBottom

Tags: jquery, callback, scroll, jscrollpane

I know that the jscrollpane fires a function when "isAtBottom" finally becomes true.

But what is the name of this function respectively how can I check if "isAtBottom" finally becomes true?

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jScrollPane doesn't fire a function for that condition, it fires an event. You can bind to the event the same way you'd bind to any other jQuery event:

```
$('.your-scroll-pane').bind(
    'jsp-arrow-change',
    function(event, isAtTop, isAtBottom, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
        // Now look at the is* parameters and do what you
        // need to do. All four of the is* parameters are
        // booleans.
    }
);
```