# Detecting bottom of div scroll (w/jScrollPane)

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have a scrollable div that will load 5 new items when scrolled to the bottom. I'm using jScrollPane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) and, despite being a great plug in, seems to prevent scrollTop() from working, so the typical method for detecting the scroll reaching the bottom does not work.

Does anyone have an alternative/ recommended method for detecting if the jscrollpane-ified div has reached the bottom?

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the plugin. Can you tell me if jScrollPane has the capability of calling a callback function any time the div gets scrolled? If so, you could test whether it's at the bottom based on the height of the scroll bar, the height of the dragger, and the position of the dragger (basically, if (heightOfDragger + draggerPositionTop === heightOfScrollBar) //at the end of the div

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer. It certainly does - I completely overlooked that while getting angry at scrolltop not working! I'll answer my own question then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved myself, with maxedison's help.

Access the api as outlined [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) and then:

```
if($('#scollpane').outerHeight() + api.getContentPositionY() >= api.getContentHeight())
{
    alert('You are at the bottom bro');
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble with a very similar question. Would you be able to start a discussion with me?

Comment: On my [live version](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/authenticate.php) I want to know whether the user has scrolled to the bottom or not. I gather I add your answer to my HTML page however where you have `'#scollpane'` what do I place in replace?

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6370241/4423554) to help get this resolved.